# Speeding up symfony 1.4 templates with memcached

Tags: php, templates, memcached, symfony-1.4

I was wondering if itwould be possible to somehow speed up symfony templates by loading the files in memcached, and then instead of doing include, grabbing them from memory? Has anyone tried this? WOuld it work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the view cache already? This built-in system makes it possible to cache the output from actions, and has a lot of configuration options, and is overridable on a per-action (and per-component) level. It works by default on a file level, but I think it is possible to configure it in a way that the action output is cached to memcached. (Or you should write this part)

If you want really lightning fast pages, you should also look at the [sfSuperCachePlugin](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfSuperCachePlugin), which stores the output as an HTML file in your public HTML folder. That way Apache can directly serve the pages, and doesn't need to start up PHP and symfony to generate the output.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for not having more time to give an explanation here but you can review the notes at:

http://www.symfony-project.org/book/1_2/12-Caching

under the heading:

Alternative Caching storage

Quote from the page:

"By default, the symfony cache system stores data in files on the web server hard disk. You may want to store cache in memory (for instance, via memcached) or in a database (notably if you want to share your cache among several servers or speed up cache removal). You can easily alter symfony's default cache storage system because the cache class used by the symfony view cache manager is defined in factories.yml."

good luck!